# list of objects to a file on ifs using Unix ls in IBM i qsh

Tags: unix, ibm-midrange

I discovered that I can use qsh to run unix commands against IBM i (as400) objects.
I want to stream a list of objects to a file on ifs using ls in IBM i qsh.  This works but output seems to be in EBCDIC and is not very readable. Is there a way to convert to ASCII?

```
ls -ails /QSYS.LIB/ERP.LIB   >  all_ERP_files.txt
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct, simply redirecting the output of `ls` within `qsh` will give you EBCDIC. But you can pipe that output through `iconv` to convert it to utf-8 like this:

```
ls -ails /QSYS.LIB/ERP.LIB | iconv -f37 -t1208 > all_ERP_files.txt
```

That `-f37` is assuming a USA CCSID (that is mine). You can replace that with yours if necessary to get a better conversion.

Considering John's answer, I tried using PASE `call qp2term`, and when I did that, I did not have to pipe the output through `iconv`, the file was created in CCSID 819.

---

For the edification of the general Unix community, `qsh` is a Unix type shell on the IBM i platform, `ibm-midrange`. This platform uses EBCDIC rather than ASCII like other Unixes.

Comment: A+ Great answer! Other places talk about changing System Values. This is much safer and obvious!

Answer (score 3):

Since Qshell (invoked by `qsh` or `strqsh`) operates in EBCDIC, there are at least a couple of workarounds you can use:

1. **Try doing the same command in PASE.**

To invoke a PASE shell (rather than Qshell), do `CALL QP2TERM` from a CL command prompt. From there, most of the same Unix-style commands are available, except the shell explicitly operates in ASCII.

2. **Convert the stream file to ASCII after the fact.**

Besides the suggestion from @jmarkmurphy, you can also use the `CPY` command in CL:

```
CPY &STMF TOOBJ(&STMF) TOCCSID(819) DTAFMT(*TEXT) REPLACE(*YES)
```

In the above, replace `&STMF` with the name of the stream file you're trying to convert. CCSID 819 is Latin-1; you can use whatever will suit you best.

Comment: Interesting John, I recreated his result first try. I wonder if there is a configuration setting that you have that makes your environment work in ASCII. I ran qsh from my 5250 emulation. Are you using `ssh`?

Comment: @jmarkmurphy - No, it was carelessness on my part. I recently changed PCs at work. On my old machine, I had my FTP client configured to always transfer in binary, no matter what. I forgot this was not the default; on my new machine, the FTP client deduced that this was a text file and did an implicit conversion. So looking at it on my PC was misleading. If I display the hex with DSPF on the raw IFS files, I get the same result as you and OP. I've edited out my foible from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For others to help in future searches: Converting to ASCII is most likely necessary when transferring data out of IBM i.

The IBM i FTP server converts EBDIC on the fly to ASCII Latin1 when **not** transferring binary. Mode ASCII is necessary.

For more Information see this [PDF for FTP Support from IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/pt-br/ssw_i5_54/rzaiq/rzaiq.pdf).